# When we install packages from ppa , are the packages downloaded at the location /var/cache/apt/archive?

Tags: apt, ppa, repository, add-apt-repository

When we install packages from ppa , are the packages downloaded at the location /var/cache/apt/archive? I am making a local repository of all the packages installed with apt-get. I see that packages in ubuntu archive repository are downloaded in archive directory before installation. I want to know if the same applies to packages downloaded from ppa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed a ppa package and packages were downloaded in /var/cache/apt/archive directory. So, apt-get downloads packages into archive directory irrespective of the source